# Android Google Maps v2: make sure function finished before continuing

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

In my app multiple markers can be added on the map, these are saved in an arraylist. Whenever the user adds a new marker to the map, it sometimes gets removed from the map after a very short time passed. Some other times the markers stay put.

The gist of it is that removeIcons() is still busy and finishes after drawIcons()

```
removeIcons();

//Redraw icons
drawIcons();
```

Remove icons is simply:

```
private void removeIcons() {
  for (Marker iconMarker : iconMarkers) {
    iconMarker.remove();
  }
}
```

**Question**: how do I make sure removeIcons finished before calling drawIcons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.

Don't remove all icons and then re-add all the icons just to add/remove 1 single icon.

That's extremely inefficient.

Keep track of the list, add one marker, draw it, and done.

It's happening because the Google Maps View handles drawing on another thread, and that thread can run while your code is running. There is nothing you can do to stop this behavior sadly.

Comment: thanks, I did have trouble removing the markers otherwise. I'll try this route